# Is $(x-t)^p$ irreducible?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

$f(x) = x^p-s = x^p - t^p = (x-t)^P$

I don't know how to show that it is irreducible... How can I use Eisenstein to show this? Is it suitable to say by Gauss' lemma, since in the question $p$ is prime, $p=(t)$ and $t \notin p^2$ so it is irreducible?

Comment: Is there a typo in the title? I think it should say $\mathbb{F}_p(t^p)$.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that is a typo

Comment: Is $t$ supposed to be a transcendental element over $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Answer (score 1):

If $t$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then so is $t^p$. Thus, $\mathbb{F}_p(t^p)\cong\mathbb{F}_p(y)$ for a transcendental variable $y$ (I switch so we are not distracted by the exponent in "$t^p$"; we want to treat it as a transcendental variable, not the $p$th power of something.)

So... is $x^p-y$ irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p(y)$? Yes. To see this, we can apply Gauss's Lemma. The polynomial $x^p-y$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p(y)[x]$ if and only if it is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[y][x]=\mathbb{F}_p[x,y]=\mathbb{F}_p[x][y]$. But as a polynomial in $(\mathbb{F}_p[x])[y]$ it is clearly irreducible, since it is of degree $1$. Therefore, it is also irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p(y)$.

Comment: Thank you Arturo

Comment: what is $y$? Is it another transcendental element?

Comment: @12589user: Yes, just a transcendental element so we are not distracted by the exponent in $t^p$.

Comment: Ahh ok! So this can be done just remaining with $t^p$ also I presume. Thank you!

Comment: @12589user:  Yes, it's just a convenient thing to do.